# Install SharePoint powershell module

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to install SharePoint powershell module into my local PC, and received error message

```
'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
```

After google, noticed that sharepoint dll is missing on my machine. My question is how to get the sharepoint dll ? Do I need to install SharePoint to my local machine ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SharePoint Online (Office 365) there's a [Management Shell available](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

If you're using any other version you indeed need to install SharePoint Server itself to get the PSSnapin on your local computer, there's no 'Management Tools only' option for SharePoint (like there is for Exchange).

You could also RDP onto an existing SharePoint Server and run your script.

Or use a PSSession to connect to the Server via PowerShell like this:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName SharePointServer01
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

To do this [PSRemoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) will need to be enabled on the Server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that you need to install/use this module on the local machine where SharePoint is installed and/or use PowerShell Remoting.